# How to check stability condition of VEC estimates in R?

Tags: r, time-series, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

I am estimating a VEC model and need to check the stability of its parameters. The vars package has a function to do this on an object of class `varest` generated by `var()` function. I would appreciate any comment regarding this.

Comment: Have you thought about converting the `ca.jo` object to a `varest` object using the function `vec2var` and applying the function on it?

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks. Yes I did, but I was using 'VECM()' of 'tsDyn' package at the time of posting this question.

Comment: So did you move on to `ca.jo` from "vars", or are you still using `VECM` from "tsDyn"? In the latter case, I do not have a good idea how to do what you want in a simple way.

Comment: Hello Richard, No, i moved back to VECM() after checking for normality and serial correlation. Also, I have just posted another question regarding VARs. Can you please have a look: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169988/irfs-and-cumulative-irfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to check for stability is obtaining the roots of the determinant (using `eigen`) of the companion matrices of lagged endogenous variables that you obtain by applying `vec2var` on the estimated VECM.

Using the example provided in the `vec2var` help page:

```
library(urca)
data(finland)
sjf <- finland
sjf.vecm <- ca.jo(sjf, ecdet = "none", type = "eigen", K = 2,
spec = "longrun", season = 4)
vec2var <- vec2var(sjf.vecm, r = 2)
```

finally,

```
> eigen(vec2var$A$A1)
$values
[1] 0.9118953 0.7204302 0.2960268 0.2323736

$vectors
            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,]  0.63464979  0.38485331  0.4915762  0.4176340
[2,]  0.13477567 -0.13850082  0.8302354  0.6888242
[3,] -0.76072394  0.91184746 -0.0499461 -0.2784035
[4,] -0.01882149  0.03520894  0.2580066  0.5230626
```

Nonetheless, as the manual of the [`vecstable`](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/tsvecstable.pdf#tsvecstable) function from Stata points out:

> ...there is no general distribution theory that allows you to
>   determine whether an estimated root is too close to one for all the
>   cases that commonly arise in practice.

Another approach, though more laborious, would be to adapt each individual equation (or the whole system as a `varest` object) from these matrices in order to assess stability using fluctuation processes, implemented in the `stability` function.